# How can I add Opportunity ID to another page reference

Tags: url

I am trying to pass opportunity Id from one class to another class and I thought of doing it through URL , but I dotn know how I can add that Opport Id to this page

```
 PageReference opptyPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(opportunity).view();
  opptyPage.setRedirect(true);

  return Page.PBXOrdering + opptyPage;
```

Comment: do you want to pass value to PBXOrdering page ?

Comment: yah , I just did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing a get parameter.

```
 PageReference opptyPage = new PageReference('/apex/PBXOrdering');
       opptyPage.getParameters().put('id', Opportunity.id);
      opptyPage.setRedirect(true);

      return opptyPage ;
```

Comment: yes that is the correct way. I was proposing the same but with your code that was not possible because you were referring something else there. :)

Comment: @Himanshu Thank you , I had to recreate it , do you know how I can get that Id in the other class?

Comment: You can use read using ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')